# how to remove a node with a garbled url

Tags: 8, nodes, uri

I have this stray node showing up in places (mainly menus) on my site - I don't know how it got created, but I would like to delete it and I can't find a way to delete it from the administration interface.

The url looks like this:

www.organization.com **/node/dc436a14-ff7d-4ff8-85f2-ee2b4f9e81ad**

and when you click it, it goes to the 404 page.

Anyone know a way to delete this node without having to go into the database?

Thanks!

Comment: You can either look up the alias on the URL Alias page in the admin, or look in the database for the alias record to see what the src path is.

Comment: The alias does not show up in the URL alias page unfortunately. It actually seems like the content itself has been deleted (the url itself has a 404 error), but the reference remains. Where in the database should i look? And is it safe to delete directly from the database?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a way to do this.

Went into the specific menu as admin, and looked through the urls each of the menu items were pointing to (painful process when you have 60 some items). Found the menu item and deleted it from the menus interface and that worked.